# sent message added twice in JSQMessageViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am using JSQMessageviewcontroller for creating a chat cliet using parse. I am sucessfull in achieving everything except "My sent message is being added twice in the jsqmessage array". Althuogh I have checked if JSQMessage array already contains that message, it should not be added, but the condition is false in case of a sent message.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import JSQMessagesViewController
import Parse

class MessageViewController: JSQMessagesViewController {

var chatWith : String?
var chattingWith = false
let incomingBubble = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory().incomingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(UIColor(red: 10/255, green: 180/255, blue: 230/255, alpha: 1.0))
let outgoingBubble = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory().outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor())
var messages = [JSQMessage]()
var updateTimer = NSTimer()
let updateDelay = 2.0
var jsqMessages : [JSQMessage] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.setup()

    updateTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(updateDelay, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {

    updateTimer.invalidate()

}
func reloadMessagesView() {
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
 }
 }

//MARK - Setup
extension MessageViewController {


func setup() {
    self.senderId = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId!
    self.senderDisplayName = PFUser.currentUser()?.username!

}
}

//MARK - Data Source
extension MessageViewController {

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.messages.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
    let data = self.messages[indexPath.row]
    return data
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, didDeleteMessageAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    self.messages.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource! {
    let data = messages[indexPath.row]
    switch(data.senderId) {
    case self.senderId:
        return self.outgoingBubble
    default:
        return self.incomingBubble
     }
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {
    return nil
}
}

//MARK - Toolbar
extension MessageViewController {
override func didPressSendButton(button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: NSDate!) {
    let message = JSQMessage(senderId: PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId!, senderDisplayName: PFUser.currentUser()?.username!, date: date, text: text)
    print("sent messages = \(message)")
    if !self.messages.contains(message) {
       self.messages += [message]
    }

    self.sendMessageToParse(message , date: date)
    self.finishSendingMessage()
 }

override func didPressAccessoryButton(sender: UIButton!) {

}


}

//MARK - Syncano
extension MessageViewController {

func sendMessageToParse(message: JSQMessage , date : NSDate) {

    let obj = PFObject(className: "Chat")
    obj.setObject((PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!, forKey: "username")
    obj.setObject(message.text!, forKey: "Text")
    obj.setObject(chatWith!, forKey: "To")
    obj.setObject(PFUser.currentUser()!, forKey: "user")
    obj.setObject(date, forKey: "dateCreatedOn")
    try! obj.save()


 }

func update() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Chat")
    query.limit = 10
    query.includeKey("user")
//        query.whereKey("To", equalTo: chatWith!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        for i in results! {

            if i.objectForKey("username") as? String == PFUser.currentUser()?.username! {

                let message = self.jsqMessageFromParseMessage(i, senderId: (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId!)!, senderDisplayName: i.objectForKey("username")! as! String)
                print("received message : \(message)")
                self.jsqMessageArray(message)
            }else {

                let message = self.jsqMessageFromParseMessage(i, senderId: i.objectForKey("To")! as! String, senderDisplayName: i.objectForKey("To")! as! String)
                self.jsqMessageArray(message)
            }

        }


    }

 }



 func jsqMessageFromParseMessage(message: PFObject , senderId : String , senderDisplayName : String) -> JSQMessage {
    let jsqMessage = JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, senderDisplayName: senderDisplayName, date: message["dateCreatedOn"] as! NSDate, text: message["Text"] as! String)
    return jsqMessage
}

func jsqMessageArray(jsqmessage : JSQMessage){

    if self.messages.contains(jsqmessage) {

    }else {
        //
        self.messages.append(jsqmessage)
        self.finishReceivingMessage()
        self.reloadMessagesView()

    }

}
}
```

Will really appreciate if anyone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably check for something more unique on the jsqMessage than just instance because it might only be checking if the pointers are equal and not if the values are the same.  Try checking on the hash property to see if the 2 messages are equivalent

Comment: How can I check the hash properties? I am not aware of it. Can you please me out?

Comment: can u tell me how did u solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method that you can implement on JSQMessageData protocol called messageHash.  It returns an Int and it is meant to be a unique id for each message.  You should be able to use that to check and see if the message is the same or not.

You would need to create an object data class that adheres to the JSQMessageData protocol instead of using JSQMessage

```
  class Message: JSQMessageData {

       func senderId()-> String {
          return //the result of currentUser()?.objectId
       }

      func senderDisplayName()-> String {
         return //the result of currentUser()?.username!
      }

      func date()-> NSDate {
         return // date
      }

      func isMediaMessage() -> Bool {
         return false
      }

      func messageHash()-> String {
         return //return a uniquely created id
      }

      func text()-> String {
         return // text
      }

  }
```

You should be able to do this on PFUser, although I am not familiar enough with Parse to tell you if this is possible or not, but your really only re-mapping existing properties to be new names so it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Thank you for this kind act. I really appreciate your help. Will definitely try to implement this way.

Comment: Sure no problem, hope it helps

Comment: Hello Bolnad! I tried the above code but could'nt end up with a solution. May be I am not aware how to use JSQMessageData protocol. Can you please help me using my above code. I'll really appreciate it.

Comment: what are you having issues with?  You should be able to add the above code to PFUser.  PFUser: JSQMessageData and then fill in the blanks with where the info is coming from.  Then you need to change your datasource in your implementation of JSQMessageViewConrtoller to handle an array of JSQMessageData.  Your messages property becomes var messages: [JSQMessageData].  Then when you pull objects out of that array, refer to the protocols to get the info.  var messageData = messages[indexpath.item]. messageData.text()